# How to remove a sink drain flange?

Tags: plumbing, drain, sink

This is on a pedestal sink. I assume it's just putty/caulk. Should I just carefully tap at it from the bottom? Would heat help?[image]

Comment: If force alone fails you - Heat the whole thing (sink and drain), then put ice just against the metal of the drain, then apply force.

Comment: I occurred to me that, it being metal, that heat would expand it, and thus that I would want to cool it. But a couple taps from the bottom knocked it off, so no heat/cool treatment was needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Yes you should. You should do exactly that.

Chances are it's stuck with putty, caulk, gunk, or a combination of those. Heat is an option, but would rarely be needed.

Comment: Hard to tell from the pic if it's set with silicone (kinda looks like that around the edge), and if so, heat would definitely not help.  If you can get a blade in there to cut some of the silicone (assuming that's what it is) between the flange and sink, that would help some.

Comment: I assume you removed any anchoring part from the underside.

Comment: Two taps with a wooden down and it came off!